# C# button click event insert twice

Tags: c#, events, button

i just can't resolve this. I have a simple page with C# with a form that stores some data in a DB. My issue is that click event fires twice, and therefore stores twice my data.
I can't find anyhere where the event is called twice. Any help? Ty! (this is my button:)

```
  <div id="submit_buttons">
      <asp:Button id="btnAgregar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnAgregar_Click"/>
  </div>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
    protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

        //insertamos proyectos
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sqlComm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO proyectos (nombre, descripcion, archivo, idRegion, idCategoria) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@nombre,@descripcion, @archivo, @region, @categoria)";
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@nombre"].Value = this.proy_nombre.Value;

        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@archivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@archivo"].Value = this.archivo.FileBytes;

        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@region"].Value = this.cmbRegion.SelectedValue;

        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@categoria", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@categoria"].Value = this.cmbCategoria.SelectedValue;

        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", SqlDbType.Text);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@descripcion"].Value = this.p_descripcion.Value;

        sqlConn.Open();

        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int lastID = (int)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();

        //insertamos concursantes
        SqlCommand sqlCommConcursantes = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommConcursantes = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sqlCommConcursantes.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO concursantes(nombre, email,titulo, idArea) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@nombre,@email, @titulo, @idArea)";
        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters["@nombre"].Value = this.c1_nombre.Value;

        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters["@email"].Value = this.c1_email.Value;

        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters.Add("@titulo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters["@titulo"].Value = this.c1_titulo.Value;

        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters.Add("@idArea", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommConcursantes.Parameters["@idArea"].Value = this.c1_area.Value;

        sqlCommConcursantes.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int lastIDConcursantes = (int)sqlCommConcursantes.ExecuteScalar();

        //asociamos proyectos con concursantes.
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
        sql = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sql.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO proyectos_concursantes(idProyecto, idConcursante) VALUES (@idP,@idC)";
        sql.Parameters.Add("@idP", SqlDbType.Int);
        sql.Parameters["@idP"].Value = lastID;

        sql.Parameters.Add("@idC", SqlDbType.Int);
        sql.Parameters["@idC"].Value = lastIDConcursantes;

        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlConn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("About.aspx");       

    }
```

Comment: yeah, sorry, i was trying something and i forgot to put it back when i posted it. Edited, ty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You execute your command twice:

```
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
int lastID = (int)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: OOH LOL! I'm so dumb. Thx lol, I never saw that, I forgot to delete that line . I 've spent like 2 hrs looking why it wasn't working lol.  Thanks!